# How to read Different lines of text in a RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to read and convert the different lines of a richtextbox in vb.net
for example if these are the lines of a RichTextBox:

```
    Hello
    Hi
```

How can I convert it to something like:

```
    Yo(Hello)
    Yo(Hi)
```

and put the result in a second richtextbox?

Comment: have you checked my suggestion ? you don't need to loop through all lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RichtextBox has a `lines` property:

```
    Dim rtb_in As New RichTextBox
    Dim rtb_out As New RichTextBox
    For Each line In rtb_in.Lines
        rtb_out.AppendText(String.Format("Foo({0})", line))
    Next
```

Always a good idea to check out MSDN for the classes you work with ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting on a new line and modifying the results:

```
Dim box1Lines as String() = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new String() { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim newLines as String = ""

For Each line As String in box1Lines

    newLines += "Yo(" & line & ")" & Environment.NewLine

Next

richTextBox2.Text = newLines
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you should use `String.Join` to accomplish it. A `one line` solution would be:

```
rtbOut.Lines = ("Yo(" & String.Join(")" & Environment.NewLine & "Yo(", rtbIN.Lines) & ")").Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

and here is the complete code where modified line is assigned to second `RichTextBox`:

```
Dim rtbIN As New RichTextBox
Dim rtbOut As New RichTextBox
rtbIN.Lines = New String() {"Hello ", "Hi"}
rtbOut.Lines = ("Yo(" & String.Join(")" & Environment.NewLine & "Yo(", rtbIN.Lines) & ")").Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```